Write speed to USB drops as disk active time increases
I would like to know the correlation between disk active time and disk transfer rate, and what the problem might be.
Using a WD Elements 3TB drive to back up a Surface Book 2 (about 650GB of 1TB drive). This used to take about five hours with Windows Backup. Started to use AOMEI Backupper, but it sent the processor up to 100%.
With Windows Backup it has always hit 97% complete in a matter of minutes and then stays at that until it finishes. Last backup it was still running at night so I left it - but it was still running the next morning - assumed there was a problem and stopped it.
Just tried again and noticed that the transfer rate seems to be about 5.4 MB/s and the active time around 92%. When the active time drops to around half the transfer rate heads up to over 90 MB/s. Even at the higher rate it will, I believe, take about 15 hours to complete and the lower rate some 15 days (that will mess up the daily backup).



